# Parsing the results of SharePoint 2013 rest api json

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I have set up a search using the rest api on SharePoint.  I can get back a json object with the results, however, I am having a hard time getting to the data I want in the JSON object.  I want specific fields from the PrimaryQueryResult specifically the Title, Author, Size, and Path.  Here is the code I am hacking at to try and get this:

```
HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(@"https://oursites.myngc.com/TS/EDMS/_api/search/query?querytext='(tequila)'");  
        endpointRequest.Method = "GET";  
        endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json; odata=verbose";
        endpointRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream webStream = endpointResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
        string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(response);
        JArray jarr = (JArray)jobj["d"]["query"]["PrimaryQueryResult"]["Relevantresults"]["Table"]["Rows"]["results"];

        responseReader.Close();
```

I have tried a lot of different combination including using a path from an online JSON editor with no luck.  Can someone help me zero in on these fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a capitalization issue. Try "Relevant**R**esults". Everything is case sensitive.

This is the path when using a JavaScript object:

```
d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results
```

Comment: That did it.  Here is the path I finally ended up using to get to the results:
(JArray)jobj["d"]["query"]["PrimaryQueryResult"]["RelevantResults"]["Table"]["Rows"]["results"][i]["Cells"]["results"];

where "i" is the row in the results to process.